# how to send email with google app accounts using python smtplib?

Tags: python, gmail, smtplib

I know how to send email by using python smtplib with normal google account. By when I try to send email with my business account, e.g. yu@mycompany.com, it doesn't work because I cannot set "less secure app access" here

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

It is said “This setting is not available for Google Apps accounts.”

Any suggestions guys?

Thank you!

Comment: What operating system are you using for this?

Comment: I am using Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

You can use google's 'App Passwords' feature. It means you can generate separate password for any application and use it for only this application.

This feature was invented to prevent compromising your primary password.

See [answer here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833).

You may try this [direct link](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords?pli=1) if it will work for you to manage passwords.